# What is the scope of lens in saltStack?

Tags: linux, puppet, augeas

I am working on Salt related stuffs, here I found **lens** inside the augeas module.I have been looked into the saltStack documentation but I could not able to figure out what it actually does ?

```
augeas.change:
    - context: /files/etc/redis/redis.conf
    - lens: redis.lns
    - changes:
       - set bind 0.0.0.0
       - set maxmemory 1G
```

Here in above rule my understanding is look for the file redis.conf and set the bind parameter to 0.0.0.0. But my question is what **lens: redis.lns** will do here ?

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Augeas is [a C library](http://augeas.net) which parses configuration files and exposes them as a tree with an API to query and modify it.

Lenses are the [bi-directional parsers](http://augeas.net/docs/lenses.html) Augeas uses for these tranformations. Each format supported by Augeas corresponds to a specific lens.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ufRzrXNKgoo) explains the principle of lenses easily.